# Problem with regexp in ansible module shell

Tags: python, regex, shell, ansible

In my ansible-playbook, task realize problem replace in file text with characters. I'm using ansible module shell with sed.

i want realize problem

txt.file: `Some text @@VAR_NUMBER_ONE@@`

new txt.file: `Some text {{VAR_NUMBER_ONE}}`

```
  - name: sed
      shell: sed -i 's|@@\([a-zA-Z_ ]*\)@@|\{{\1}}|g' txt.file
```

I've got fatal error

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
>       "msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating 's|@@\([a-zA-Z_ ]*\)@@|\{{\1}}|g'. Error was a , original message: unexpected char u'\\' at 25"
>   }

Comment: Try `sed -i 's|@@\([^@]*\)@@|{{\1}}|g' txt.file`. Not sure, but you might need to double each backslash.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"replace in file text with characters"*

*txt.file* before: `Some text @@VAR_NUMBER_ONE@@`

*txt.file* after: `Some text {{VAR_NUMBER_ONE}}`

A: The task below does the job.

```
- replace:
    path: "txt.file"
    regexp: '^(.*)@@(.*)@@$'
    replace: '{{ "\1" + "{{" + "\2" + "}}" }}'
```

The *regexp* string explained:

- `^` beginning of the string
- `(.*)` any sequence stored in `\1`
- `@@` matches @@
- `(.*)` any sequence stored in `\2`
- `@@` matches @@
- `$` end of the string

The *replace* string is created by concatenation of 4 strings because in YAML `{{` and `}}` is used to expand variables.